# TypeError: Object.entries requires that input parameter not be null or undefined in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, object

I am trying to loop over objects which I am getting from calling an API But after setting the data in state `setNodesData` and getting the data from `nodesData` but when I am trying to do that I am getting an error saying:  `TypeError: Object.entries requires that input parameter not be null or undefined in React Native`

I have also tried `for(const i in nodesData)` but still I am getting an error saying `expression expected`

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (apiHeaders) {
      axios
        .get(
          "https://test-myways-anfhsya-asq.myways.in/api/****",
          {
            headers: apiHeaders,
          }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("API Call")
          console.log(res?.data);
          setNodesData(res?.data);
        })
        .catch((err)=>{console.log("error:",err)});
    }
  }, [apiHeaders]);

  return (
    
  
      {
      Object?.entries(nodesData).forEach((i) => (
        <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <TouchableOpacity
               onPress={(props) => props.navigation.navigate("CoursesPlaylistScreen")}
              style={{
                flexDirection: "row",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                flex: 1,
              }}
            >
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                  flex: 1,
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: "#000000",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                  }}
                >
                  {i}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
```

data:

```
{
    "week1": {
        "content": [
            {
                "moduleName": "HTML Crash course",
                "moduleVideos": [
                    {
                        "title": "HTML Crash Course For Absolute Beginners",
                        "link": "https://youtu.be/*****",
                        "duration": "01:00:42"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "moduleName": "CSS Crash course",
                "moduleVideos": [
                    {
                        "title": "CSS Crash Course For Absolute Beginners",
                        "link": "https://youtu.be/*****",
                        "duration": "01:25:11"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

I want to get only weeks But I getting errors and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please edit your post to contain only the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) required to find the problem. Attaching the entire file - which is over a hundred lines of possibly irrelevant code - will just make it harder to find the problem.

Comment: @EldarB. Oh. Okay, thanks I have edited the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is likely occurring on the initial render. You are attempting to convert `undefined` into an array of object entries.

```
const [nodesData, setNodesData] = useState(); // <-- undefined initial state!

...

Object?.entries(nodesData).map( ... // <-- blows up with error
```

Test

```js
const nodesData = undefined;
console.log(Object.entries(nodesData)); // error
```

```js
const nodesData = {};
console.log(Object.entries(nodesData)); // []
```

### `.map` vs `.forEach`

Your edit when you changed `Object?.entries(nodesData).map( ...` to `Object?.entries(nodesData).forEach( ...` won't return anything to be rendered as `.forEach` is technically a void return. Revert that change back to use `.map`.

Also, since each "value" of the entry is still an object you'll need to select the object values you want to render. If there are any nested arrays, they need to also be mapped to JSX.

## Solution

Provide valid initial state. An empty object should suffice.

```
const [nodesData, setNodesData] = useState({});
```

And if on the off-hand chance the `nodesData` state later becomes undefined, use a null check or provide a fallback value.

- `nodesData && Object.entries(nodesData).map( ...`
- `Object.entries(nodesData || {}).map( ...`

Ideally though you should maintain the state invariant to at least always be a defined object.

### Render the `nodesData` week keys

If you just need the keys then you can:

- Render the key from the entries (*recall the entries is an array of key-value pairs, i.e. `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2], ...]`*)

  ```
   Object.entries(nodesData).map(([week, data]) => (
     <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
       ...
         <Text .... >
           {week} // "week1", "week2", etc...
         </Text>
       ...
     </View>
  ```
- Use `Object.keys` to get an array of *just* the keys

  ```
   Object.keys(nodesData).map((week) => (
     <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
       ...
         <Text .... >
           {week} // "week1", "week2", etc...
         </Text>
       ...
     </View>
  ```

Comment: I have applied this and I am not getting errors now but I am also not getting weeks. Can you please help me How can I get weeks from the data? Do I need to change something in {i}?

Comment: @HarshMishra `.forEach` is a void return. (*I noticed your last code edit changes this*) Does it work if you switch back to using `.map` to map the data to JSX?

Comment: changing it to `.map` giving me an error `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {content, Bonus}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: @HarshMishra Yes, I also added a note about that. Each element you are mapping is still an object, so you'll need to decide what part of each "week" object you want to render. For example, `i.content` is an array, so you will need to map this array to JSX, and for each element in that array there is a `moduleName` string and ` moduleVideos` array that could be rendered.

Comment: I just want to render weeks. LIke week 1, week 2 ...not their data.

Comment: @HarshMishra I see, also pretty trivial. See updated answer in the solution section.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
… Object?.entries(nodesData).map((i) => ( …
```

To:

```
… nodesData && Object.entries(nodesData).map((i) => ( …
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation?